# add item with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

im trying add item with ajax, all work, except the view doesnt refresh, when i force refresh, new product in the list, here is code http://pastie.org/1533605
what's wrong? im using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "products")) %>");
```

And I guess you'd better do `$("#products").append(...)` so that ou keep the former content instead of replacing it.

To conclude, consider keeping this kind of behavior on the client side, look at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: ty, but this dont work :( i see this railscasts, but i wanna figure out my problem, js doesnt wanna render my new item, maybe its some kinda error in controller?

Comment: im trying todo appendTo, instead append, and this is append my new item at the top of table, so ajax work, but work kinda strange, append doesnt appear at all

Answer (score 1):

okay, i figure it out, some problem with my markup
sry of this stupid question

$('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @product))%>').insertBefore('.height');
that was final solution